# How to browse a file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, path, filesystems

I have one created one folder called "MYFOLDER" inside my folder in have one pdf file test.pdf.

I have one button named browse and the textfield. As soon as I click on the browse button I need to navigate through the folders and select the test.pdf file (Like GMAIL Attachment). After selecting particular file I need to set the file path in the text field.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not codes?

i appreciated NSFileManager.

```
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/MYFOLDER"];
    NSArray *pdfList = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.pdf'"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", pdfList);
```

Comment: if i know the folder i can use like what you have said. If i dont know how can i navigate multiple folders.

Comment: I am getting error: 'NSPredicatepredicateWithFormat' undeclared (first use in this function). i don't know why it is coming. @bitmapdata

Comment: oops, sorry. i forgot about the spacing [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: i've been corrected codes..

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumeratorAtPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/enumeratorAtPath:)

> Returns a directory enumerator object that can be used to perform a
> deep enumeration of the directory at the specified path.
>
> - (NSDirectoryEnumerator *)enumeratorAtPath:(NSString *)path Parameters
>
> path
>
> ```
> The path of the directory to enumerate.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> An NSDirectoryEnumerator object that enumerates the contents of the
> directory at path.
>
> If path is a filename, the method returns an enumerator object that
> enumerates no files—the first call to nextObject will return nil.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf";];
```

Comment: What happens if the file is saved in documents directory?

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to list the files and folders in the folder, and keep on browsing.

```
    NSError *error;
    NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:homeDirectory error:&error];

    for(int i = 0; i < [dirContents count]; i++){
         //Here you can browse dirContents
         NSString *fileName = [dirContents objectAtIndex:i];
    }
```

Comment: getting Error like [NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e05400'

Comment: There. Try looking at apple documentation about file handling.