# How can i get saved documents and upload in iphone device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload

I have a requirement i need to browse document files saved in iPhone and upload selected document . I have no idea how to get saved documents from iPhone . Please help . Thanks in advance .

Comment: And what do you need to upload them to?

Comment: try this 

[Saving files][1]


[uploading /browsing][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454842/upload-and-send-file-by-browsing-a-file-from-iphone

Answer (score 1):

```
try this
```

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios): [saving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619719/write-a-file-on-ios)

[upload and browse files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454842/upload-and-send-file-by-browsing-a-file-from-iphone)